# Excessive number of Ethernet Connections with constant Internet Dropouts

Tags: networking, google-chrome, ethernet

I have no idea how to even begin to solve this problem, so would appreciate some advice.  My internet has been dropping out for **just** my Windows 10 Laptop, no other devices on the network.  I consistently receive **ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED** errors in Google Chrome, which makes the computer almost inusable.  Upon trying to solve this problem I found this in my Network and Sharing Center:
[image]

I have a Killer e2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controller network adapter.  The computer was upgraded from Windows 8 to 10 but I don't think this caused the problem, as it worked fine for a number of weeks before this occurred.

I've already re-installed the drivers for my network adapter which doesn't seem to have helped.  `ipconfig` shows similar results to the screenshot above.

Does anyone have any advice they can give?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a VPN? Or AutoKMS?

Comment: Not using a VPN.  Don't think I'm using AutoKMS, how can I tell?  Sorry to be vague.

Comment: AutoKMS is used for the activation of Microsoft Office products. KMS creates these Multiple TAP-Win32 Adapters to keep the license in check. See https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/34embb/multiple_tapwin32_adapter_oas/

Comment: Ahhhh I think this may have solved my problem.  Looks like I was searching for the wrong keywords.  Did you want to post an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Done. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Windows 10 is creating Multiple TAP-Win32 Adapters

This may be caused by VPN clients or by AutoKMS.

> AutoKMS is used for the activation of Microsoft Office products. KMS creates these Multiple TAP-Win32 Adapters to keep the license in check.

Source [Multiple TAP-Win32 Adapter OAS](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/34embb/multiple_tapwin32_adapter_oas/)